# Jquery .css() disabling height changes made with media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a trouble debugging a site that's not acting very responsively. I have media queries like so:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px)
{
    .radio-page {
        height: 1470px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1199px)  
{
    .radio-page {
        height: 1525px;
    }
}
```

(There are a few more breaks at larger screen dimensions but I don't think they are relevant)

I haven't specified a height for this class at dimensions less than 768, instead opting for the following javascript/jquery:

```
  function confirmer() {
        if ($(window).innerWidth() < 767) {
            var inHeight = $('.iright-4 p').offset().top +
                $('.iright-4 p').height() - $('.inner-radio').offset().top;

            var outHeight = inHeight + $('.inner-radio').offset().top - 42;

            $('.inner-radio').css('height', inHeight + 20);
            $('.radio-page').css('height', outHeight + 50);
        }

        // debug code to report element height
        console.log('radio-page is ' + $('.radio-page').css('height'));
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        confirmer();
        $(window).resize(confirmer);
    });
```

All is well when it loads. The problem occurs specifically when the window is resized from below 767px into something higher. For some reason the media queries no longer change the height value of the .radio-page element, despite the javascript changed being isolated to < 767px. .radio-page stays at exactly whatever height it was when the resize passed the threshold.

Also, I have a suspicion that the confirmer function is being disabled altogether when the window is > 767px,  because I'm losing console updates. All is well when I re re-size to < 767px (the jquery operates as intended).

Any help is most appreciated,

Comment: add an `else` after your `if` with `$(...).css('height', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLUTION](http://jsbin.com/podaka/1/edit?js,output)

```
function confirmer() {
  if ($(window).innerWidth() < 767) {
    ...
  } else {
    $('.inner-radio').css('height', '');
    $('.radio-page').css('height', '');
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When the javascript code sets your elements to have a specific height at < 767px, it is changing the style attribute of those elements. When you resize to 767 px or above, your CSS is trying to take over for the javascript, but that style attribute defining the height is still there. One possible solution is to clear it in your code:

```
  function confirmer() {
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < 767) {
        var inHeight = $('.iright-4 p').offset().top +
            $('.iright-4 p').height() - $('.inner-radio').offset().top;

        var outHeight = inHeight + $('.inner-radio').offset().top - 42;

        $('.inner-radio').css('height', inHeight + 20);
        $('.radio-page').css('height', outHeight + 50);
    }else{
        $('.inner-radio').css('height', '');
        $('.radio-page').css('height', '');
    }

    // debug code to report element height
    console.log('radio-page is ' + $('.radio-page').css('height'));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    confirmer();
    $(window).resize(confirmer);
});
```

As per the jQuery docs on [$.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $(
>   "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property. It does not, however, remove a
>   style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or 
>   element.

In regards to losing console updates, I cannot answer that part of the question. Perhaps you are getting updates, but because the height value is the same, your browser recognizes them as identical messages and collapses them into one? Check if there is a small number next to your message. Here's an example from Chrome:

[image: Collapsed console messages]